# Each user post to php page

Tags: php, jquery

**Hello overflowers!**

The problem i'm stuck on at the moment is following.

- I have managed to add a "✓" to selected users.
- I have added a "data-id" attribute to each listed user.

The thing I'm trying to figure out is how I have post the users `data-id` from jquery to my php page.

Jquery:

```
  task_takers = [];
  var i = 0;
  $(".new-task-takers ul.select_takers li").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
      if($(this).find('.fa').length > 0){
        $(this).find('.fa').remove();
      }else{
        $('<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>').insertBefore($(this).find("div"));
      }
      console.log("Selected:", $(this).data("id"));
      i += 1;
      task_takers[i] = $(this).data("id");
      console.log(task_takers);
      console.log(i);
    });
  });
  console.log(task_takers);
```

PHP:

```
$task_takers = isset($_POST['task_takers']) ? $_POST['task_takers'] : NULL;
var_dump($task_takers);
```

All I'm getting is a NULL

---

**Edit:**

I got it too work, but the thing is the array is getting flooded if you select the user and un-select and re-select.

Array:
[1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 3]

As you can see it spams ID: 3

Comment: look at your console and use error reporting as well as html source and var_dump(); the tools to debug

Comment: I think you're looking for [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Added new information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send data to the php script in order to make it work.

Here is a little example of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) from the docs :

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

I usually use it as following :

```
  $("form").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/relative/path/to/php/script.php",
      data: $("form").serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
      }
    });
  });
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

Since your last edit :
You could solve this by using [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove duplicated items of the array from the PHP script.

For example :

```
php > $arr = array("1" => 2, "2" => 3, "3" => 3, "4" => 3, "5" => 3, "6" => 3);
php > print_r($arr);
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 3
)
php > $uniq_arr = array_unique($arr);
php > print_r($uniq_arr);
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

Comment: I'm already using ajax on my submit form to include the array, but the information for each user isn't being sent.

Comment: Ok @Samuel, I saw your Edit and I edited my answer along with it.

Comment: But the array is from console.log via jquery not php.

Comment: Yes, this is the array that you send to php with Ajax, isn't it ?